# Expansion of $(1+3x)^{-5/3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binomial-theorem

In ascending powers of $x$, and including the term $x^3$. Attempted with loads of expansion but need to know a more sophisticated way of expanding. $\text{  }$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^n\binom{-5/3}{n}x^n$, where $\binom{-5/3}{n}=\frac{-5/3(-5/3-1)(-5/3-2)...(-5/3-n+1)}{n!}$, which you can prove by induction by taking successive derivatives and evaluating at $x=0$.

Comment: Sophisticated or not, an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin has a unique Taylor series at the origin. The extended binomial theorem kindly provides such series.

Comment: What is the taylor series and how would you find his functions taylor series? How is it relevant to the functions expansion?

Comment: Induction ah nice one

Comment: $$(1+x)^n=\sum\limits_{r\geq0}\binom nrx^r$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(3 x+1)^{5/3}}$$
derivatives are 
$$f'(x)=-\frac{5}{(3 x+1)^{8/3}},\;f''(x)=\frac{40}{(3 x+1)^{11/3}},\;f'''(x)=-\frac{440}{(3 x+1)^{14/3}}$$
so we have $f(0)=1;\;f'(0)=-5;\;f''(0)=40;\;f'''(0)=-440$

Taylor expansion at $x=0$ is
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2!}f''(0)x^2+\frac{1}{3!}f''(0)x^3+O(x^4)$$
that is
$$f(x)=1-5x+20x^2-\frac{440}{6}x^3+O(x^4)=\color{red}{1-5x+20x^2-\frac{220}{3}x^3+O(x^4)}$$

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand, will just write this down and work through other examples, can you get rid of the "O(x4)" ; what does that term mean?

Comment: $O(x^4)$ means that if you stop at $x^3$ the sum from $x^4$ term to the end, that is the error in this approximation, is no more than $x^4$, if you are near to $x=0$.  You can write $$f(x)\approx 1-5x+20x^2-\frac{440}{6}x^3$$